# Parameters in "use [database]" clause

Tags: sql-server

I want to use parameters in `use [database]` command, but it runs successfully without changing the database under usage.

How can I fix it? Thanks a lot

```
declare @database varchar(100)
SET @database = 'transform'

declare @sqlstring nvarchar(500)
set @sqlstring = 'use '+ @database

exec sp_executesql @sqlstring
```

Comment: i don't know your requirement, but you can refer the database like this

`SELECT * FROM Transform..[TableName]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It changes the database, but within context of sp_executesql

Try this to confirm:

```
set @sqlstring = 'use '+ @database + ';  select DB_NAME()'
```